# I get an error when adding an and statement where should I insert the and statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT * from customer WHERE customer.cust_id in (SELECT orders.cust_id from orders and orders.order_date > '2008-10-27')
```

I'm trying to pull the query from where customers have placed an order and it was after 2008-10-27

Answer (score 1):

The `and` in the subquery whould be a `where`:

```
select * 
from customer 
where customer.cust_id in (
    select orders.cust_id from orders where orders.order_date > '2008-10-27'    
)
```

I would recommend `exists` instead; it scales better agains large datasets. Also, table aliases come handy to shorten the query and make it more readable:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where exists (
    select 1 
    from orders o
    where o.cust_id = c.cust_id and o.order_date >  '2008-10-27'
)
```

Comment: wow thanks! before I could even fix the formatting!